# A few basic questions about getting started with Titan and Tinkerpop

Tags: titan, tinkerpop3

This morning I decided to try out Titan.  I've used both Neo4j and OrientDB, and was going to implement a polyglot persistence model using one of those graph databases; however, since I am already using Cassandra, I decided to try out Titan.

I've read through the Titan docs, as well as the Tinkerpop docs, but a few things are still unclear.  Both Neo4j and OrientDB are pretty much plug-and-play; since Titan seems like more of a layer on top of a db backend like Cassandra, I'm unsure of how to start with setting it up.  I can start the gremlin console and connect to my Cassandra cluster, and I can start titan server, both from the console.

My main question is, am I supposed to install titan as a service?  Do I make my own init scripts, or use supervisor/monit/etc to manage it?  Basically, what is the right way to keep everything running and available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titan starts as an application by itself; configuring and running embedded applications of backends (Berkeley, Embedded-Cassandra, ...) or connects to already started server or cluster of Cassandra or DynamoDB.

This means that you can pass a single configuration file that includes all information you want Titan to use. In this config file, you could ask Titan to embed a backend (start and maintain it by itself) or connect to a local/remote instance.

These are [several examples](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/tree/1349a5edd1149a00da6a37a4584aed25a8164a14/titan-dist/src/assembly/cfilter/conf) of config files that you should have a look at.

As a quick introduction, download Titan 1.0.0 and run its gremlin console by moving to main directory and running

```
bin/gremlin.sh
```

Inside the gremlin console, you could run something like

```
TitanGraph g = TitanFactory.build().
               set("storage.backend", "berkeleyje").
               set("storage.directory", "/tmp/graph").
               open();
```

Or you could load a configuration file like this:

```
 TitanGraph g = TitanFactory.open("path/to/properties/file")
```

Dive deep [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/arch-overview.html).